# Header doesn't extend with page width

Tags: width, page-layout

No idea why this is happening. My head is a standard div, nothing special. When the content extends the page width, the header won't extend with it. See screenshot:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7830551/Screenshots/e5zxgw58gxm9.png

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Type setting width to `100%`:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
  <!-- Your header HTML here -->
</div>
```